# AWS GLUE Not able to write Delta lake in s3

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue, delta-lake

I am working on AWS Glue and created an ETL job for upserts. I have a s3 bucket where I have my csv file in a folder. I am reading the file from s3 and want to write back to s3 using delta lake (parquet file) using this code

```
from delta import *
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog") \
    .getOrCreate()
inputDF = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load('s3://demonidhi/superstore/')
print(inputDF)
# Write data as DELTA TABLE
inputDF.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("s3a://demonidhi/current/")

# Generate MANIFEST file for Athena/Catalog
deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, "s3a://demonidhi/current/")
```

I am using a jar file of delta named 'delta-core_2.11-0.6.1.jar' which is in s3 bucket folder and i gave the path of it in python libraby path and in Dependent jars path while creating my job.
Till the reading part the code is working just fine but after that for the writing and manifesting it is not working and giving some error which I am not able to see in GLUE terminal. I tried to follow several different approaches, but not able to figure out how can i resolve this. Any help would be appericiated.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `spark.config()` notation will not work in Glue, because the abstraction that Glue is using (the GlueContext), will override those parameters.

What you can do instead is provide the config as a parameter to the job itself, with the key `--conf` and the value `spark.delta.logStore.class=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.storage.S3SingleDriverLogStore --conf spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension --conf spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog`